# AJAX ModalPopup update panel contents based on change in panel controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AJAX Modal Popup panel that contains a RadioButtonList, 2 labels and 2 DropDowns.  I want to update the Labels and DropDowns when a radio button is selected.  My attempt at this posts back which causes the ajax popup to disappear.

aspx called on image click:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlModalContainer" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <asp:ListItem Text="Test 1" Value="1" Selected="True" />
      <asp:ListItem Text="Test 2" Value="2" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblFoo" Text="Foo" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblBar" Text="Bar" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDogs" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsDogs" DataTextField="Dog" DataValueField="DogID" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCats" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsCats" DataTextField="Cat" DataValueField="CatID" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind (vb.net):

```
Protected Sub rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles rblTest.SelectedIndexChanged
   ' ???
   ' Make it change lblFoo.Text and lblBar.Text as well as the DataSource for the DDLs
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an UpdatePanel within `pnlModalContainer`.

Comment: Even though pnlModalContainer is already within an UpdatePanel?  They should be nested?

Comment: Yes.  Basically, your PostBack is telling the page to replace everything in your UpdatePanel (in this case the markup for the Modal Panel).  When this happens the Modal no longer exists on the page so it can't continue to be displayed.  Nesting UpdatePanels is fine.  Make sure to surround only the items you need to update in their own panel.